# How to create a list of scripts and add these as components onto a new gameobject

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I would like to create a list of scripts and add these as components onto a new gameobject. I would like the scripts I'm going to add to inherit from Monobehaviour and my base class 'Fruit'.

So far I have the test code to create an empty object and try and put two scripts on it (so far no luck)

```
public class List_Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Fruit> fruitList;


    void Start () {
        fruitList  = new List<Fruit>();

        fruitList.Add(new Pear());
        fruitList.Add(new Apple());

        foreach(Fruit fru in fruitList){
            print ("A fruit was found and it was a " + fru);
        }
        GameObject tInstance = new GameObject("test");
        for (int i = 0; i < fruitList.Count; i++){

            Fruit inst = fruitList[i];
            tInstance.AddComponent<inst>(); 

/* This doesn't work at all and throws an error in the inspector
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `inst' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? */

            print (inst);

        }
    }

}
```

And I have a base fruit class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Fruit {

}
```

and then child classes

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Apple : Fruit {


}
```

etc etc.

If I try inheriting from Monobehavior in the base class Fruit, the child classes will not be added to the list. It prints

```
A fruit was found and it was a null
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
```

I also seem to be struggling to add these scripts as components regardless of inheriting from Monobehaviour or not though

Thanks in advance for any help or code you might have!

Jim

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the line of your error wrong. It's this:

```
tInstance.AddComponent<inst>();
```

That's a generic method `AddComponent<T>`, where `T` is a type, not an instance. So `AddComponent<Pear>()`, for example, is valid, but `AddComponent<new Pear()>()` is not.

To add a component when you don't know the type at compile type, you can use [`AddComponent(Type)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html). You can use it like this:

```
tInstance.AddComponent(inst.GetType());
```

This gets the type of the instance and passes it to `AddComponent`. Unity will create a component with the right type and attach it to `tInstance`.

Comment: Thanks! That was a useful reply. However now that I am able to do this, Unity warns me that I am not allowed to create a 'new' monobehaviour "You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword."

Comment: @Jim That error should be fairly easy to search on. It's exactly as it says, you can't use `new`. One option here is to use the return from `AddComponent`, since it returns the new component it creates. Another is to not use components.